# Non-unique derivatives at $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

$A=\{0\le y\le x^2,x\ge0\}\subset\Bbb{R}^n$. Let $ f(x,y)=1$ for all $(x,y)\in A$

I'm trying to find more than one $L:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}$ that satisfy the definition of differentiability at $f(x,y)=(0,0)$

Clearly one $L$ that works is $\left[ 0 \text{ }0\right]$ since $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\|f(h)-f(0)-[0\space0]h\|}{\|h\|}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{0}{\|h\|}=0$$

Not sure how to find another one unless I can somehow define $L$ to depend on $h$ but I don't think that's valid.

Comment: Why do you think that more than one $L$ exists?

Comment: Because I was told to find more than one... mainly.  Also, since (0,0) is not an interior point of $A$ then my inclination is that it is not differentiable at that point

Comment: Hmm okay. Interesting that my teacher would ask me to prove something false

Comment: Your teacher is right. But I that $(0,0)$ is not an interior point of $A$ is does not mean that it is not differentiable, as for any point $(x,x^2)$ with $x>0$, the function is differentiable.

Comment: I can't make any sense out of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let us try an arbitrary linear $L(x,y) = ax +by$ as derivative.

Then we must find that $\lim_{h_x,h_y \to 0}\frac{ |ah_x + bh_y| }{\sqrt{ h_x^2 + h_y^2}}$ for any path $(h_x,h_y)$ in $A$ goes to $0$.

So we can take $h_y =0$ and $h_x > 0$,then we must have $0 = \lim_{h_x \to 0}\frac{ |a| h_x}{h_x}=|a|$, so $a=0$.
Then consider $0 \le h_y=f(h_x) \le h_x^2$, as $(h_x,h_y) \in A$, then we have
$$\lim_{h_x \to 0} \frac{ |b |f(h_x)}{\sqrt{h_x^2 + f(h_x)}} = |b|\lim_{h_x \to 0} \frac{ h_x^2}{\sqrt{h_x^2 + f(h_x)}} \le |b| \lim_{h_x \to 0} \frac{ h_x^2}{\sqrt{h_x^2 }} = |b|\lim_{h_x \to 0} h_x = 0$$
So we have $L(x,y) = by$ is the derivative at $(0,0)$ for any $b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Note that for any $(x,y) \in A \backslash \{(0,0)\}$ we either have $(x,y+h)\in A$ or $(x,y-h) \in A$ for small enough $h$. Note that we still have $(x+h,y) \in A$ for all $h$, so we still find $a=0$ for $L(h_x,h_y) = ah_x + bh_y$. However, we can now consider the path where $h_x =0$ and $h_y>0$ if $(x,y+h_y) \in A$.
This gives $\lim_{h_y \to 0} \frac{ | b h_y|}{\sqrt{ h_y^2}} = \lim_{h_y \to 0} |b| \frac{ |h_y|}{|h_y|} = |b|$, which should be $0$, so $b=0$.
Likewise, we have $b=0$ when $(x,y-h_y) \in A$.

So for any point $(x,y) \in A \backslash \{(0,0)\}$, we have that the derivative is given by $L = 0$.